# What is the difference between this.unbind vs this.$el.unbind in backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I bind some events in backbone view and in `this.destoryview()` method, i called `this.unbind()`. But it not unbinding events. When some event happaned it called bounded method twice.

Then i change `this.unbind()` call by `this.$el.unbind()`, then it working properly.

```
events:{
        'click #closeButton' : 'clearSearch',
        // some events
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        this.container = options.container;         
    },

    render: function() {

        if(this.oSearchContext.isAdvancedSearchEnabled() == true)
        {
            this.$el.html(this.advancedSearchSummaryViewTemplate);              
        }
        else
        {
            this.$el.html(this.advancedSearchTemplate);
        }           
        this.container.append(this.$el);
    },
```

destroyView method with this.unbind()

```
destroyView : function()
    {
        if ( this.oAdvancedSearchSummaryView )
            this.oAdvancedSearchSummaryView.destroyView();

        if ( this.oAdvancedSearchDetailsView )
            this.oAdvancedSearchDetailsView.destroyView();

        // unbind all events
        this.unbind();   // this.$el.unbind() working perfectly

        // empty the rendered element
        this.$el.empty();
    }
```

Can you please explain me about differnce between both methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `view.bind` (or the modern `view.listenTo` or `view.on`) in order to subscribe to another backbone component such as listening to a change event in a backbone model.

You use `view.$el.bind` (or the modern `view.$el.on`) in order to listen to user interaction in the DOM.

Same logic applies to `unbind` or the modern `off`

Similar syntax and API, different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `bind` I'd suggest to use [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)'s `listenTo`:

```
view.listenTo(model, 'change', view.render);
```

Once the `view` is destroyed, all the bindings will be automatically removed (unbinded);

Comment: Event binded like `'click #closeButton' : 'clearSearch' `

Edited in code as well.